# How to pass data from activity to service?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**MainActivity.java**

```
String username = userName.getText().toString();
String pass = password.getText().toString();
Intent serviceIntent;
serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Services.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("username",  username);
serviceIntent.putExtra("pass", pass);
startService(serviceIntent)
```

**Services.java**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            System.out.println("Starting the Service ................" + intent.getExtras().getString("username")); //returns null
        }
        return START_STICKY;
}
```

If I hardcoded the *username* in **MainActivity.java** like

**MainActivity.java**

```
String username = userName.getText().toString();
String pass = password.getText().toString();
Intent serviceIntent;
serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Services.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("username",  "AAA");
serviceIntent.putExtra("pass", pass);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

I getting the data in services like.

**Services.java**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            System.out.println("Starting the Service ................" + intent.getExtras().getString("username")); //returns AAA
        }
        return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of bound service in android?

Comment: Yes, So I need to bind the service and then to pass the data ?

Comment: checkout this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String username = userName.getText().toString(); is already not null? Did you check it?
My solution is:

- Declare `username` at the beginning after the class (local variable of the class)
- You can also create a class to save data as:

```
public class Common {
    public static String username;
}
```

In **MainActivity.java**

```
Comon.username = userName.getText().toString();
```

After get value of username in **Services.java** with:

```
String username= Common.username
```